# Docker for angular: Build result is not being copied in the /usr/share/nginx/html folder

Tags: angular, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a docker image for an **angular 17** app. There are several variants of codes I've found online, below being the simplest one.

```
FROM node:21-alpine3.18 AS build
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /app/dist/myapp-frontend /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I'm able to build and push successfully push the image to docker hub. However, when I try to access the app in the browser, I only get the default nginx page.

[image: Default nginx page]

My understanding is that the build result will be copied in the **/usr/share/nginx/html folder**. Yet, when I log in that folder, I only see nginx default files.

[image: Listing /usr/share/nginx/html container folder content]

Am I missing something in my Dockerfile above?

Comment: check your `angular.json` file and look for this key `outputPath` this is the location where the built *.js etc files will be created. Check if you have a subfolder called `browser` in that location if so. Update your `COPY` line

Comment: Can you check this [link](https://tiangolo.medium.com/angular-in-docker-with-nginx-supporting-environments-built-with-multi-stage-docker-builds-bb9f1724e984) which will be useful to you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... directly in the question body as [code block]**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [ask]. Note that this is also a valid remark for your self answer.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

all credit to @robert

Normally, the result of the build is outputted in the `dist/<app-name>`. I run a ng build on an angular v16. That's the behavior.

It seems like **angular 17** is outputting the build result in a folder called browser.  Yet, this is the configuration in the angular.js, it's showing `dist/<app-name>`. Yet, it still adds folder called **browser**.

[image]

Therefore, updating the Dockerfile worked.

`COPY --from=builder /app/dist/myapp-frontend/browser /usr/share/nginx/html`

[image]

Thank you so much @rober.